# Executing test on remote agent fails with "Target machine actively refused it"

Tags: testing, automated-tests, visual-studio-2013, coded-ui-tests, remote-server

I am attempting to run tests on a remote agent by using a test controller that is on the same remote machine. I have set up my TestSettings file as follows:

```
<RemoteController name="MachineName" />
<Execution location="Remote">
    <AgentRule name="AllAgentsDefaultRole">
    </AgentRule>
```

When I tell MSTest to execute a selected test in release or debug mode, it successfully builds the project and then returns "Failed to queue test run 'run name': No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it." Visual Studio 2013 has been installed on the controller/agent machine, and the agent, controller, and client can all communicate successfully. Default ports are being used for communication (6901 and 6910), and telnet is able to connect. How do I get the test executing successfully?

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer.  Agents cannot debug remotely, and while the build I was executing against in the above post was "release" (in one instance), I was still attempting to debug.  If I select the test and click "Run" instead, it executes successfully on the remote agent.